# How do I copy a canvas-based graph to the clipboard in Webkit?

Tags: javascript, webkit, copy-paste, qwebview

We've got a Chart.js based chart and we want to be able to allow the user to select the graph, copy the graph and paste the graph into a non-browser window (e.g. Word), and have an image of the graph's current state successfully migrate over.

The page is hosted in a QWebView (which is WebKit based).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking into converting the canvas to an image?

```
// Converts canvas to an image
function convertCanvasToImage(canvas) {
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    return image;
}
```

Taken from [here](http://davidwalsh.name/convert-canvas-image).

Then you have the canvas as an image and you can take it from there.